# Как сохранить и проверить существует ли пользователь в приложении

Tags: android, firebase, auth

Здравствуйте сегодня добавил FireBase auth в приложение и у меня вопрос.
Как при выходе из приложения аккаунт сохранился и следующим входе в программу открывалась не окно авторизации а окно профиля

Comment: вроде так [`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(функция, принимающая объект пользователя и обновляющая информацию о нём в приложении)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)

Comment: Можете привести пример для android

Comment: вы бы написал что для android, а то ведь непонятно... Под андроид получить текущего пользователя вроде можно так: [`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)